# SpringBoot and HikariCP relationship

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp, data-connections

SpringBoot already is managing dataConnection then why is Hikari CP needed?

I have just started using SpringBoot so do not know much about SpringBoot and Hikari relation, although i read about Hikari but couldn't find any explicit explanation about its relationship with Springboot in presence of Spring data connection.

I read that Hikari is used when we need heavy db operations with lots of connections, if it is true then should we not use Hikari in follwoing scenario?

Scenario:

There is a small application, having maximum 8-10 REST calls once in a month or maximum fortnightly.That application needs to perform some probability and statistics related calculation.

Users login on that app at a time are of maximum 2-3 in numbers.

Do we still need to use Hikari?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to communicate with the database from your application. You can either open a new DB connection any time you wish execute some query there, or you have a connection pool. Connection pool is a collection of reusable connections that application uses for DB communication. As establishing a new connection is relatively expensive operation, using connection pool gives you a significant performance improvement.

HikariCP is one of the connection pools libraries available in java and SpringBoot uses it as a default. As you don't need to do anything special to have it in your application, just enjoy your free lunch :)

Comment: thank you so much for the response. But would you please have a look at the scenario given in the OP, do we need to utilize Hikari specifically for that small application?

I was using PersistenceJPAConfig without extending Hikari and it was working fine but as soon as I extend PersistenceJPAConfig with Hikari my application broke, even the server is not starting. Am I missing somehing?

 What if I do not extend it with Hikari and what to do if I need to set connection.timeout with out Hikari?

Comment: I repeat my answer: "As you don't need to do anything special to have it in your application, just enjoy your free lunch". If you have any problems with it, then please post another question describing "as soon as I extend PersistenceJPAConfig with Hikari my application broke, even the server is not starting"

Answer (score 0):

HikariCP is used as the default connection pool in SpringBoot2, it was TomcatJDBC in SpringBoot 1. You must be using it as a default in your settings. You can overwrite it by setting another connection pool in your setting properties if you need. Please find more details about the connection pools and the default configurations of Spring Boot versions [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hikari).

Answer (score 0):

Hikari is the default DataSource implementation with Spring Boot 2. This means we need not add explicit dependency in the pom.xml. The spring-boot-starter-JDBC and spring-boot-starter-data-JPA resolve it by default. To sum up, you require no other steps with Spring Boot 2.
Compared to other implementations, it promises to be lightweight and better performing.

Tuning Hikari Configuration Parameters:

- **spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout** = 20000 #maximum number
  of milliseconds that a client will wait for a connection
- **spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle**= 10 #minimum number of idle
  connections maintained by HikariCP in a connection pool
- **spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size**= 10 #maximum pool size
- **spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout**=10000 #maximum idle time for
  connection
- **spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime**= 1000 # maximum lifetime in
  milliseconds of a connection in the pool after it is closed.
- **spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit** =true #default auto-commit
  behavior.

HikariCP is a reliable, high-performance JDBC connection pool. It is much faster, lightweight, and has better performance as compared to other connection pool APIs. Because of all these compelling reasons, HikariCP is now the default pool implementation in Spring Boot 2. In this article, we will have a closer look to configure Hikari with Spring Boot.